# Using lazy properties in a client / server application with webservices and SOAP

Tags: hibernate, web-services, soap, lazy-loading

We have a huge client / server application. The server exposes multiples webservices with most of the services retrieving / filling different parts of a complex business model.

Currently there is no lazy functionality so the full model is retrieved and returned every time a request is made even if the client only needs one property value.

For example, consider the next model diagram:

[image: Model A]

Then we have a service to get the model depending on different criteria:

[image]

Tens of clients use these methods but every one needs different parts of the model filled. As we do not have lazy loading functionality we retrieve the full model on every call even when the client may need just one property value. This increases the time required by the server to query from DB the information and the time required to serialize / deserialize the objects.

In the server we are using Hibernate but with everything EAGER due to the lack of the functionality on the client.

How can we implement this mechanism thru SOAP webservices? Is there something already available?

Comment: You would need to do this on the Hibernate side. Lazy loading of models is not a SOAP function and AFAIK there is nothing in the SOAP world to support it.  In short it will be a custom function. You can use pagination of results in Hibernate. Also you would need to look at why these designs pull everything. Bit hard to answer as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would value a couple of options

1. **Lazy loading**: modify the hibernate layer to load only the objects you need in each request.
2. **Filter SOAP objects**: Each service returns only the information that the client needs cleaning unnecesarity objects and properties of the entire model.

The first option will improve response times, both by increasing server performance (fewer queries) and avoid serializing unnecessary objects, but it requires reimplementing the server database layer and services that use it

The second option only minimizes serialization and deserialization time, and network transmission time, but the implementation is very localized and allows you to maintain the implementation and even redesign the server in the future (for example to implement option 1) without changing the interface.

The first option seems the most logical, but you have to consider other affected services that you can have on the server and the reimplementation time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue with the first approach is that there are tens of clients of the GetModelA(FilterA) webservice method and every client needs a different set of data from the ModelA. Currently there is no way to communicate these needs to the server and when lazy properties reach the serialization boundary they get lost. With the second approach we have a similar problem because there is no way to communicate to the server what can be filtered out or not and IMHO if we are capable of communicating this we should go for option 1.

Comment: I agree, you need to redesign the SOAP services interface in the first step so that the client can indicate in some way the data that he / she will need. Maybe you can propose a version 2.0 with the new service specification so that you can migrate to clients gradually while you reimplement the server service with option 1 or 2

Comment: anda que hablando en inglés con un maño ;)

Comment: jajaja, soy de la franja, en catalán y castellano me defiendo mejor!

Comment: `Currently there is no way to communicate these needs to the server`, which needs? are you talking about client needs?, if so, AFAIK, there is no way to prevent the server from loading the entire model, if it doesn't know what the client wants!!!

Comment: @O.Badr: of course, that's what the question is about. As the lazy loading mechanism is pretty common today I was looking for an existent mechanism to do it over SOAP so the client can communicate its needs to the server.